# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'error' of 'panelMembersList' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-reducers

I am trying to load data from `Django REST API` server using `redux` and `axios`, similar approach I used in my other screens like Products, BlogPosts, they are working fine, Now I need to load another model from `api` but I am not sure why is this error coming...
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'error' of 'panelMembersList' as it is undefined.`

Problematic Code
`panelMembersList.js`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, Card, Container, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
// import PanelMember from '../components/PanelMember'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Paginate from '../components/Paginate'
import { listPanelMembers } from '../actions/panelMemberActions'

function PanelListScreen({history}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const panelMembersList = useSelector(state => state.panelMembersList)
    const {error, loading, allPanelMembers, page, pages } = panelMembersList

    let keyword = history.location.search
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listPanelMembers(keyword))

    }, [dispatch, keyword])

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Our Panel Members</h3>
            {loading ? <Loader />
                : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                    :
                    <div>
                        <Container variant='success'>
                        <Row>
                                {allPanelMembers.map(allPanelMembers => (
                                    <Col key={allPanelMembers._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                                        <Card style={{minWidth:'auto', maxWidth:'auto'}}   >
                                        
                                        </Card>

                                        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' ,  height: '30rem'}} className= "card border-success mb-2 my-0 p-2 rounded">
                                        <Card.Header>Joined Date : {allPanelMembers.createdAt}</Card.Header>
                                        <Link to={`/panel/${allPanelMembers._id}`}>
                                        <Card.Img className='mb-0 my-0 p-0' src={allPanelMembers.image} />
                                        </Link>
                                        <Card.Body>
                                            <Link to={`/panel/${allPanelMembers._id}`}>
                                                <Card.Title as="h5"><strong>{allPanelMembers.name}</strong></Card.Title>
                                            </Link>
                                            <Card.Text as="div">
                                            <div className="my-0">
                                                <Rating value={allPanelMembers.rating} text={`${allPanelMembers.numReviews} reviews`} color={'#f8e825'} />
                                            </div>
                                        </Card.Text>
                                        <Link to={`/panel/${allPanelMembers._id}`}><Button variant="btn btn-outline-success">
                                        Read More </Button></Link>
                                        </Card.Body>
                                        </Card>

                                    </Col>
                                ))}
                        </Row>
                        <Paginate page={page} pages={pages} keyword={keyword} />
                        </Container>
                    </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default PanelListScreen
```

When I load this screen I am getting following error

```
 12 | function PanelListScreen({history}) {
  13 |     const dispatch = useDispatch()
  14 |     const panelMembersList = useSelector(state => state.panelMembersList)
> 15 |     const {error, loading, allPanelMembers, page, pages } = panelMembersList
  16 | 
  17 |     let keyword = history.location.search
  18 |     useEffect(() => {
```

that indicating error is undefined, Can you helpout solving this issue.

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import {
    productListReducer,
    productDetailsReducer,
    productDeleteReducer,
    productCreateReducer,
    productUpdateReducer,
    productReviewCreateReducer,
    productTopRatedReducer,
} from './reducers/productReducers'

import {
    panelMemberListReducer,
    panelMemberDetailsReducer,
    panelMemberReviewCreateReducer,

} from './reducers/panelMemberReducers'


import {
    blogPostListReducer,
    blogPostDetailsReducer,
    blogPostReviewCreateReducer,
} from './reducers/blogReducers'

import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers'

import {
    userLoginReducer,
    userRegisterReducer,
    userDetailsReducer,
    userUpdateProfileReducer,
    userListReducer,
    userDeleteReducer,
    userUpdateReducer,
} from './reducers/userReducers'

import {
    orderCreateReducer,
    orderDetailsReducer,
    orderPayReducer,
    orderListMyReducer,
    orderListReducer,
    orderDeliverReducer,
} from './reducers/orderReducers'

import  {
    messageListReducer,
    messageDetailsReducer,
}  from './reducers/messageReducers'


const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    productDelete: productDeleteReducer,
    productCreate: productCreateReducer,
    productUpdate: productUpdateReducer,
    productReviewCreate: productReviewCreateReducer,
    productTopRated: productTopRatedReducer,

    panelMemberList: panelMemberListReducer,
    panelMemberDetail: panelMemberDetailsReducer,
    panelMemberReviewCreate: panelMemberReviewCreateReducer,

    cart: cartReducer,
    userLogin: userLoginReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
    userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
    userUpdateProfile: userUpdateProfileReducer,
    userList: userListReducer,
    userDelete: userDeleteReducer,
    userUpdate: userUpdateReducer,

    orderCreate: orderCreateReducer,
    orderDetails: orderDetailsReducer,
    orderPay: orderPayReducer,
    orderListMy: orderListMyReducer,
    orderList: orderListReducer,
    orderDeliver: orderDeliverReducer,

    blogPostList: blogPostListReducer,
    blogPostDetails: blogPostDetailsReducer,
    blogPostReviewCreate: blogPostReviewCreateReducer,

    listMessages: messageListReducer,
})


const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo') ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) : null


const shippingAddressFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress') ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')) : {}


const initialState = {
    cart: {
        cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage,
        shippingAddress: shippingAddressFromStorage,
    },
    userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

actions

```
export const listPanelMembers = (keyword = '') => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PANEL_LIST_REQUEST })

        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/panel${keyword}`)

        dispatch({
            type: PANEL_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PANEL_LIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

reducer

```
export const panelMemberListReducer = (state = { allPanelMembers: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PANEL_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, allPanelMembers: [] }

        case PANEL_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                allPanelMembers: action.payload.allPanelMembers,
                page: action.payload.page,
                pages: action.payload.pages
            }

        case PANEL_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

api end point
`http://localhost:8000/api/panel/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to post my answer what I was doing wrong, basically before I was using `allPanelMembers` at the endpoint to access data, Every time when I see my other endpoints with this same approach are working fine but there was One difference I was not using camelCase there, this resulted me to change variables at `django` side might this could help. then I changed `allPanelMembers` to `members` without camel case.  and that solved the issue. Someone told me once to use camelCase at backend if we are using react in the frontend, But now I learned this is not correct.

**Correct Code :**

```
#views.py
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAllPanelMember(request):
    query = request.query_params.get('keyword')
    if query == None:
        query = ''

    #originaly this variable was named allPanelMembers
    members = PanelMember.objects.filter(
        name__icontains=query).order_by('-createdAt') 

    page = request.query_params.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(members, 8)

    try:
        members = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        members = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        members = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if page == None:
        page = 1

    page = int(page)
    #print('Page:', page) If you want to see in termnial 
    serializer = PanelMemberSerializer(members, many=True)
    return Response({'members': serializer.data, 'page': page, 'pages': paginator.num_pages})
```

**frontend**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, Card, Image, ListGroup, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
// import PanelMember from '../components/PanelMember'

import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Paginate from '../components/Paginate'

import { panelMemberList } from '../actions/panelActions'


function PanelListScreen({ history }) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const panelList = useSelector(state => state.panelList)
    const { error, loading, members, page, pages } = panelList
    
    let keyword = history.location.search

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(panelMemberList(keyword))

    }, [dispatch, keyword])
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Panel</h1>
            {loading ? <Loader /> : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message> : <div>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        {
                            members.map(item=>(
                                <Col key={item._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                                    <Card.Header>By : {item.name}</Card.Header>
                                </Col>
                            ))
                        }</Row></Container></div>}
                <Paginate page={page} pages={pages} keyword={keyword} />
            </div>

    )
}

export default PanelListScreen
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is being accessed before the useSelector hook returns the data or that the main object is undefined in your redux store. What you can do is check if this object does exist then deconstruct

example:

```
const panelMembersList = useSelector(state => state.panelMembersList)
const [panelData, updatePanelData] = useState({
  error: '',
  loading: false, 
  allPanelMembers: [], 
  page: 0, 
  pages: 0
});

useEffect(() => {
  if(panelMembersList) updatePanelData(panelMembersList)

}, [panelMembersList])
```

or fill that object in your redux store with defaults data to prevent being identified as undefined

```
const initialState = {
  panelMembersList: {
   error: '',
   loading: false, 
   allPanelMembers: [], 
   page: 0, 
   pages: 0

  }
}
```

hope my answer helped you solve your problem

Comment: I updated question with store.js code, please take a look if there is any mistake ?

Comment: In `initialState` If i add the code as u suggested then remaining original code would be the same ?? @technolaaji

Comment: @FaisalNazik yes, if you added the second option by adding it to your state then your original code would be the same no changes needed

Comment: I tried, Same thing happening, I used second approach as you suggested and then again `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'error' of 'panelMembersList' as it is undefined.`

Comment: Do you think there could be something wrong in `reducers` or `actions`

Comment: I m adding them in the question please take a look into them as well/.

Comment: @FaisalNazik your initial state in store.js file doesn't include panelMembersList hence that is why it shows as undefined. cart and userLogin are in the initialState so they are not undefined while panelMembersList is not there so it will be undefined by nature till you add it to your store by dispatching an action that would add them to your redux store

Comment: I also load blog posts they are loaded fine without adding into initial state and the products also were not added in initial state

Comment: I mistakenly made edit into your answer, decline that